# Show the user how many remaining chars left to him on a memoEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a memoEdit on my form, And I limited the user for 1024 chars.
I added a Label under this memoEdit (as I marked in the attached image), and I want when the user create something on this memoEdit to show him the remaining chars.
How can I do that ?

the attached image:

[image]

Comment: Could be a simple: `label1.Text = "Chars available: " + (1024 - memoEdit.Text.Length).ToString();`

Comment: Lol. Can we build your website for you? If you can't do this why are you in development?

Comment: it's a winForm not a website, and I posted this question because the MemoEdit doesn't have an event like this e.KeyChar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the  [MemoEdit Members](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsMemoEditMembersTopicAll) documentation

> **EditValueChanged** - Fires immediately after the edit value has been
>   changed. (Inherited from BaseEdit)
>
> **EditValueChanging** - Fires when the editor's value is about to be
>   changed. (Inherited from BaseEdit)

```
void me_EditValueChanging(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ChangingEventArgs e)
{
   var memo = (sender as MemoEdit);
   var maxChars = memo.Properties.MaxLength;
   lblContactWithCharCount.Text = memo.Text.Length + "/" + maxChars;
}
```

Check the another solution for this: [Add character counter to MemoExEdit control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424171/add-character-counter-to-memoexedit-control)

*Subscribe to the Popup Event of the MemoExEdit control, then inside that subscribe to the EditValueChanging Event.*

Hope this help..